# Labels falling out of the box

Tags: html, css

Yeah, my titles suck :p

So I have a container, which contains `<div>`s. Dotted in this container are `<span>`s that mark off labels. These `<span>`s have `position:absolute` to make them not interfere with the layout of the `<div>`s.

```css
#container {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:270px;
}
#container>div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:4px;
}
#container>span {
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccf;
}
```

```html
<!-- Please forgive the lack of spaces - this DOM is dynamically generated -->
<div id="container"><span>Marker</span><div></div><div></div><span>Marker</span><div></div><span>Marker</span><div></div><div></div></div>
```

In Internet Explorer, this works fine.
In Chrome, it does not. The label falls out of the box.

I understand why this happens - it's because the `<span>` has zero width and height within the flow of the document, allowing it to squeeze into the zero remaining space.

But I'm wondering if there's any other way to achieve the effect I want here?

EDIT: [Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqP8a.png), [Chrome's bad effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRdRr.png)

Comment: could you post a image of the desired effect? it might make it a little easier :)

Comment: @JacobGray Done, sorry for not putting those in first time XD

Comment: So, you are saying you want to give the spans width?

Comment: How should it look like? I don't understand what is the point :/

Comment: @JacobGray The width should be auto, fitting the text of the label itself. As shown in the screenshots, Chrome is putting the label on the previous line because - as an `absolute` element - it has zero width in the document flow and therefore "fits", whereas IE places the element where it would normally do so, before removing it from the flow as expected. Essentially, IE calculates where it should be *before* removing it from the flow, whereas Chrome calculates it *after* removing it from the flow.

Comment: Oh, and you dont want to use display block, because it will mess all the labels up. So, would using display block on every second span be an option?

Comment: @JacobGray Not really. It would work in this specific case but I need it to work for any number of `<div>`s between them. Also the "real thing" has six columns, I just used three here, but an ideal solution will not rely on the number of columns (or can be easily adjusted to work with N columns)

Comment: So, you could use display block on the last span, you would just have to find out how to select just it with css

Comment: @JacobGray Thanks for your comments, you've helped me come up with a working solution :)

Comment: Okay, I am still trying to come up with a css way that doesn't rely on the number of columns

Comment: So, what I am getting is that for every 2 divs, you want a span label, correct? So, could you wrap the divs and the label in a container, then float each container?

Answer (score 1):

don't really quite get where you want them, something like this ? added display block to the span.

```css
#container {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:270px;
}
#container>div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:4px;
}
#container>span {
  display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccf;
}
```

```html
<!-- Please forgive the lack of spaces - this DOM is dynamically generated -->
<div id="container"><span>Marker</span><div></div><div></div><div></div><span>Marker</span><div></div><div></div></div>
```

**strong text**

Comment: Ooh, I see, because `display:block` will force the element onto a newline... Ah, but that would cause a problem if the marker is halfway on a row.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing ideas from @Billy and with help from @JacobGray in the comments, the following solution applies `display:block` to `<span>`s, but only if the immediately follow an Nth `<div>`, N being the number of columns.

It works, but I'm not too happy with it being dependent on a constant number of columns - not great for responsive design ;) Better solutions are of course welcome.

```css
#container {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:270px;
}
#container>div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:4px;
}
#container>span {
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccf;
}
#container>div:nth-of-type(3n)+span {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Please forgive the lack of spaces - this DOM is dynamically generated -->
<div id="container"><span>Marker</span><div></div><div></div><span>Marker</span><div></div><span>Marker</span><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding display:block to the span is what I'd suggest, or putting a marker span inside every div you want to label.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, try this. Put tags `<span>` into each `<div>` that you want have a "label". Add `position:relative` to all `<div>` and set the properties `top` and `left` for the `span`.

Ps. I've modified your code below, but you should use classes

```
#container {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:270px;
}

#container>div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:4px;
  position: relative;/* added */
}

#container>div>span {/* modified */
  position:absolute;
  background:#ccf;
  top:-5px;/* added */
  left:-5px;/* added */
}

<div id="container"><div><span>Marker</span></div><div></div><div><span>Marker</span></div><div><span>Marker</span></div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: While that may work, unfortunately it won't be enough in this case, because `<div>`s may be hidden when search filters are applied, causing the marker to disappear if its containing element has been filtered out.